# Angular 16 - Ngx-org-chart is not working with angular 16

Tags: d3.js, ngx-charts, orgchart, angular16

enter image description here

[image]

Getting erorr in installation only.

'NgxOrgChartModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
ngx-org-chart.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ngx-org-chart) which declares NgxOrgChartModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

installation I followed- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-org-chart
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/mumincelal/ngx-org-chart/issues/72